# SQL combining queries in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 3 queries I have gotten to work fine individualy in BigQuery, but I want to combine these 3,

```
WITH dates AS (
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY), DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))) AS Date
), survey_query AS(
    SELECT 
      AWS_ID_ AS agent_name,
      IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(Quality_Date, '/'), FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d', PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', Quality_Date)), Quality_Date) AS Date,
      CASE
        WHEN COUNTIF(survey1 != '' AND survey1 != 'NA') = 0 THEN ''
        ELSE CAST(COUNTIF(survey1 != '' AND survey1 != 'NA') AS STRING)
      END AS survey1_count,
      CASE
        WHEN COUNTIF(survey1 != '' AND survey1 != 'NA') = 0 THEN ''
        ELSE CAST(COUNTIF(survey1 = '1') AS STRING)
      END AS survey1_sum,
      CASE
        WHEN COUNTIF(survey1 != '' AND survey1 != 'NA') = 0 THEN ''
        ELSE CONCAT(ROUND((COALESCE(COUNTIF(survey1 = '1') / COUNTIF(survey1 != '' AND survey1 != 'NA')) * 100), 2), '%')
      END AS survey1_avg,
      CASE
        WHEN COUNTIF(survey5 != '' AND survey5 != 'NA') = 0 THEN ''
        ELSE CAST(COUNTIF(survey5 != '' AND survey5 != 'NA') AS STRING)
      END AS survey5_count,
      CASE
        WHEN COUNTIF(survey5 != '' AND survey5 != 'NA') = 0 THEN ''
        ELSE CAST(IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN SAFE_CAST(survey5 AS FLOAT64) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CAST(survey5 AS FLOAT64) END), 0) AS STRING)
      END AS survey5_sum,
      CASE
        WHEN COUNTIF(survey5 != '' AND survey5 != 'NA') = 0 THEN ''
        ELSE CAST(IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN SAFE_CAST(survey5 AS FLOAT64) IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CAST(survey5 AS FLOAT64) END), 2), 0) AS STRING)
      END AS survey5_avg
    FROM `combined_quality`
    GROUP BY agent_name, Date
    ORDER BY agent_name, Date DESC
), ter_query AS (
    SELECT 
      AWS_ID_ AS agent_name,
      FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', CAST(A_Closing_Date AS STRING))) AS Date,
      CAST(COUNT(A_TER_Claims) AS STRING) AS TER_Count,
      CAST(IFNULL(SUM(A_TER_Claims), 0) AS STRING) AS TER_Sum,
      CASE
        WHEN COUNT(A_TER_Claims) = 0 THEN ''
        ELSE CONCAT(ROUND((IFNULL(SUM(A_TER_Claims), 0) / COUNT(A_TER_Claims)) * 100, 2), '%')
      END AS TER_Percentage
    FROM `ter_currentyear`
    GROUP BY agent_name, Date 
)
SELECT 
  d.Date,
  COALESCE(s.agent_name,t.agent_name) AS agent_name,
  CASE
    WHEN IFNULL(s.survey1_count, '') = '0' THEN ''
    ELSE IFNULL(s.survey1_count, '')
  END AS survey1_count,
  IFNULL(s.survey1_sum, '') AS survey1_sum,
  IFNULL(s.survey1_avg, '') AS survey1_avg,
  CASE
    WHEN IFNULL(s.survey5_count, '') = '0' THEN ''
    ELSE IFNULL(s.survey5_count, '')
  END AS survey5_count,
  IFNULL(s.survey5_sum, '') AS survey5_sum,
  IFNULL(s.survey5_avg, '') AS survey5_avg,
  IFNULL(t.TER_Count, '') AS TER_Count,
  IFNULL(t.TER_Sum, '') AS TER_Sum,
  IFNULL(t.TER_Percentage, '') AS `TER%`
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN survey_query s ON DATE(d.Date) = DATE(s.Date)
LEFT JOIN ter_query t ON d.Date = DATE(t.Date) and t.agent_name=s.agent_name
ORDER BY agent_name, d.Date DESC
```

current output is

```
Date    agent_name  survey1_count   survey1_sum survey1_avg survey5_count   survey5_sum survey5_avg TER_Count   TER_Sum TER%
6/25/2023   Agent1  2   2   100%    1   4   4           
6/24/2023   Agent1  2   2   100%    2   10  5           
6/21/2023   Agent1  2   2   100%    2   10  5           
6/20/2023   Agent1  2   2   100%    2   10  5   2   0   0%
6/19/2023   Agent1  2   2   100%    2   10  5   3   0   0%
```

Expected output would be (notice it ads TER data for 6/23)

```
Date    agent_name  survey1_count   survey1_sum survey1_avg survey5_count   survey5_sum survey5_avg TER_Count   TER_Sum TER%
6/25/2023   Agent1  2   2   100%    1   4   4           
6/24/2023   Agent1  2   2   100%    2   10  5           
6/23/2023   Agent1                              0   1   0%
6/21/2023   Agent1  2   2   100%    2   10  5           
6/20/2023   Agent1  2   2   100%    2   10  5   2   0   0%
6/19/2023   Agent1  2   2   100%    2   10  5   3   0   0%
```

I am struggling with the joins,

In essence I want to display for the last 15 days, the ter_query and survey_query per agent per day

The problem with the output is that there is ter_query data for 6/23, However since there is no survey_query  for Agent1 on 6/23 it omits adding ter_query because its lookin to join on date and name,

If I remove t.agent_name=s.agent_name, I get data from ter_query  that does not match the agnet_name, because its only looking to match the date

I almost feel like I want to join the ter_query twice,
once for when it matches date and name and a 2nd time to where date matches and names don't match

Comment: to join all need identical column where you join the tables, your query is unclear which they are, so it is hard to tell  make an abbriviate version of your table with only necessary column with data and tell us how your result should be a [mre]

Comment: thank @nbk, I thought adding that would just create extra fluff, as the individual queries work, the probe I am having is grouping them

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding but does something like `LEFT JOIN ter_query t ON d.Date = DATE(t.Date) and (t.agent_name is null or t.agent_name=s.agent_name)` help you?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to follow your lead on a superset of dates, you can do the same with the agents, then merge back in.

So for example:

```
WITH agents AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT AWS_ID_ AS agent_name
  FROM `combined_quality`
  UNION DISTINCT 
  SELECT DISTINCT AWS_ID_ AS agent_name
  FROM `ter_currentyear`
), dates AS (
  SELECT Date, agent_name
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY), DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))) AS Date
  CROSS JOIN agents
)
....
```

Now your dates CTE should have all combinations of agents and dates from both datasets....so you can use dates' date and agent_name for a superset like you were doing for dates before, and filter out what you want to filter (if you don't want null entries etc).

Comment: Thank mike, I ended up doing something similar, making a unique Id with name and date for both queries and doing a  "union distinct" on it

Answer (score 0):

I neded up making a unique ID with combining name and date

```
CONCAT(AWS_ID_,IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(Quality_Date, '/'), FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d', PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', Quality_Date)), Quality_Date)) as agent_date,

CONCAT(AWS_ID_,FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', CAST(A_Closing_Date AS STRING)))) as agent_date,
```

and then doing a union distinct with that key and joining on that.

```
 SELECT
    survey_query.agent_date FROM survey_query
    UNION DISTINCT 
  SELECT  
    ter_query.agent_date FROM ter_query
  )
```